# Transmission of information over long distances

Tags: entanglement, communication

I am reading that entangled particles can share information across long distances and the speed is usually faster than the speed of light...so am I right in assuming that future communications in the world will be without satellites and cell phone towers? Two entangled computers can talk instantaneously ...say between New York and Mumbai?  I sit in New York and feed in "A" in my computer, that information shows up in my friend's computer in Mumbai? Only thing is these two computers (processors/monitors) need to be entangled during manufacture?

Comment: You cannot use entangled particles for FTL communication; see [the no-communication theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem).

Comment: **Related:** [Quantum entanglement for FTL network communication?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21/quantum-entanglement-for-ftl-network-communication)

Answer (score 5):

No. As far as we know, entangled states do not permit faster than light communication. You might be able to use them for things like doubling bandwidth (see superdense coding) or sending quantum states, but that will all happen at the speed of light (or slower).

It is true that entangled states do seem to know *something* about the constituent elements faster than they ought to know. If the two parties make measurements on the entangled state, although the individual outcomes are random, the measurement results display correlations. However, these correlations between measurement results cannot be used to communicate anything.

The other thing that must be emphasised is that it's not quite so simple as "these two computers (processors/monitors) need to be entangled during manufacture". Every communication action that uses entanglement *consumes* that entanglement. So, you need a constantly replenishing supply.