# Can we teleport a human or send information faster than light using quantum teleportation?

Tags: teleportation, faster-than-light

What does quantum teleportation mean? Is it something that will allow us to send information faster than the light? Can we teleport a human with it?

Comment: **Related:** [Quantum entanglement for FTL network communication?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21) & [Transmission of information over long distances](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5302).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In conclusion, NO and NO, respectively.

Quantum teleportation does not mean *instantaneous* disappearance and reappearance of information at another spatial point. Quantum teleportation in plain English means *moving* a [quantum state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state) from one place to another using quantum operations and quantum measurement, which are connected by classical as well as quantum channels or both. This does not exceed the speed of light in any sense and does not violate the theory of special relativity. There is no faster than light (FTL) communication in the basic [Teleportation protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation) because it is restricted by the speed of light as it uses an ordinary *classical channel* as a necessary requirement to attain its perfection in probability.

Teleporting a human is a very subjective question today. Because it is not a quantum object to be described by a quantum state. A human is a macroscopic object which is completely classical. To this date, the biggest size of objects that are teleported (to about $2\ \mathrm{km}$ range) is the size of *[buckyballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminsterfullerene)* or similar objects (this means teleporting their quantum states - in the sense of information). Teleporting anything classical would be quite metaphysical at this point, it would also bring the questions of *consciousness* and other hypotheses into the framework which are not yet modeled or accepted by the science community. One way may be to scramble - teleport - re-assemble such objects, but do they retain their macroscopic properties then? It is a question which is more philosophical to this point.

Check out some of these links to catch up with the latest breakthrough in quantum teleportation regarding range, loop-holes, security, etc:

- [New Atlas: Chinese satellite shatters quantum teleportation distance record](https://newatlas.com/quantum-entanglement-satellite-distance-record/50071/)
- [MIT Technology Review: First Object Teleported from Earth to Orbit](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/608252/first-object-teleported-from-earth-to-orbit/)
- [Wikipedia: Loopholes in Bell test experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopholes_in_Bell_test_experiments)