# Can we characterize isotropic states via representation theory?

Tags: representation-theory

The only bipartite states $\rho$ invariant under any $U\otimes \bar U$ transformation are isotropic states. More precisely, as discussed *e.g.* in [quant-ph/0109124](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0109124) in Section 4.4, a state $\rho$ is invariant under any such transformation *iff* it is a mixture of maximally entangled and maximally mixed states:
$$\rho = p \mathbb{P}_+ + (1-p) \frac{I_N\otimes I_N}{N^2},$$
for some $p\in[0,1]$, where $N$ is the dimension of the underlying spaces (assumed to be equal), and $\mathbb{P}_+\equiv |+\rangle\!\langle+|$ projection onto the maximally entangled state $|+\rangle\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_{k=1}^N |k,k\rangle$.

This was shown by some of the same authors in [quant-ph/9708015](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9708015), though if I understand correctly the main ideas were already discussed before in ([Werner 1989](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.40.4277)).
A rough sketch of the proof as presented in [quant-ph/9708015](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9708015) is as follows:

1. Let $A$ be $U\otimes\bar U$ invariant (for all unitaries $U$), and consider its matrix elements on the standard canonical (product) basis. By direct examination of what the invariant condition entails for unitaries $U$ that only act nontrivially on a single basis element, we observe that the only possible nonzero matrix elements are those of the form $A_{nn,mm}$ and $A_{nm,nm}$ for some (possibly equal) indices $n,m$.
2. Investigating the consequences of the condition when $U$ is a two-element permutation, we further find that invariance implies the form $A=bB+cC+dD$ for some $b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$, where $B\equiv\sum_{m\neq n}|mn\rangle \!\langle mn|$, $C\equiv\sum_{m\neq n}|mm\rangle\!\langle nn|$, and $D\equiv\sum_{m}|mm\rangle\!\langle mm|$.
3. Considering now unitaries of the form $U=\tilde U_2\oplus I_{N-2}$ for some two-dimensional rotation $\tilde U_2$, we see that $D$ is not actually invariant, and thus $d=0$.
4. Imposing the condition $\operatorname{tr}(A)=1$, using $\operatorname{tr}(B)=N(N-1)$ and $\operatorname{tr}(C)=0$, we find that $b=1/[N(N-1)]$.
5. Observe that we ended up with an isotropic state for some $p\in[0,1]$, using the explicit expressions $\mathbb{P}_+=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{m,n}|m,m\rangle\!\langle n,n|$ and $I=\sum_{m,n}|m,n\rangle\!\langle m,n|$.

I have no issues with the proof above, but it's quite laborious. Is there a more direct (if more abstract) approach to obtain this result? For example, by using representation theory to characterise the irreps of the $\mathbf U(N)$ representation $\eta(U)(\rho)\equiv (U\otimes\bar U)\rho (U\otimes\bar U)^\dagger$? My hope was that starting from the simple observation that isotropic states are invariant under such transformations, we have
$$\rho = \int dU\, (U\otimes\bar U)\rho (U\otimes\bar U)^\dagger,$$
and being the latter the commutant of the representation, it can be split into a direct sum of projections of $\rho$ onto the different irreps.

Would this work? My main issue is that I'm not sure how to fully characterise the irreps of this particular representation of $\mathbf U(N)$ on the space $\mathbf{GL}(\mathbb{C}^N\otimes\mathbb{C}^N)$.

Comment: I always note that this proof for only pure states, which seems easier (https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.07731 uses Schur's lemma so that's almost representation theory). Obviously we know that maximally mixed states also have this property, but proving no other convex combination swaps states around appropriately seems a bit more involved